# How to chain a conditional asynchronous callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

In a node.js express project I want to implement a switch-to-user function for admin users. The admin can either type the username or the user-id in a box. Below is the code to process this request. The problem is that if the first database call failed, I need to repeat it with another kind of query, before continuing with the login code. How can I add a conditional asynchronous call before the call to `req.login`?

```
router.route('/switchuser')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        mongoose.model('Users').findById(req.body.idOrName, function (err, user) {
            if (!user) {
                mongoose.model('Users').findOne({ username: req.body.idOrName }, function (err, user_) {
                    user = user_;
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(404);
                        res.send("User not found " + err);
                    }
                });
            }
            req.login(user, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(404);
                    res.send("There was a problem switching the user: " + err);
                }
                else {
                    res.format({
                        html: function () {
                            res.redirect("/");
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: The if statement isn't happening after `req.login`. Do you mean to say that `req.login` is not waiting for `mongoose.model('Users').findOne(...)`? With the callback pattern, the only way to "wait" for something is to invoke the code inside of the callback when it completes.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I mean!

Comment: Bummer that someone closed this :(

Comment: What I was going to post is that mongoose models return `Query` objects which have `then` methods, making them "thenables" which can be treated as Promises. You should be able to use `async` functions and do `await` instead of using callbacks. Should make things a bit cleaner.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. You are experiencing callback hell. This can be solved with callbacks (when done right) but you might consider looking into Promises or Async/Await. It cleans up the code quite a bit

Comment: You will have to put the `login` code into a `then`. In this case, you would need some sort of promise for the `else` case too. So something like `if (!user) { p = mongoose.model... } else { p = Promise.resolve(user); } p.then(...)`. Or you chain your promises with that first `findById`.

Comment: @deceze Why close the question if you are going to answer in a comment?

Comment: @Spidy Essentially the question is answered in the dupe, I'm just trying to give a little more specific nudge. If that doesn't help, the question should be specified more. Generally this question is asking for "how to wait for asynchronous result", to which the answer is explained in the dupe.

Comment: I've rephrased it, now it's sufficiently distinct.

Comment: Though I think the real answer here has little to do with async callback chains and more with an `$or` query querying for both fields simultaneously.

Comment: @deceze so you closed it, linked a similar but not quite right duplicate, then its reopened and you reword it? What is happening in this thread is why SO has such a bad rep, abuse of power and gatekeepers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing callback hell. When a user is not found by ID, you start a second callback. The problem is your login as method executes outside of this second callback which means it doesn't wait for the response. Callback hell can quickly cause a lot of duplicate code. One solution is to pull your common bits of code out into functions. Below is one example of how you might do that. Notice that `loginAs` may be called in two different spots depending on whether the user was found by ID, or required an additional lookup.

```
router.route('/switchuser')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        mongoose.model('Users').findById(req.body.idOrName, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                sendErrorResponse(err);
                return;
            }

            if (user) {
                loginAs(user, req, res);
                return
            }

            mongoose.model('Users').findOne({ username: req.body.idOrName }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    sendErrorResponse(err, req, res);
                    return;
                }

                if (!user) {
                    sendNotFoundResponse(req, res);
                    return;
                }

                loginAs(user, req, res);
            });
    });
});

function loginAs(user, req, res) {
    req.login(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404);
            res.send("There was a problem switching the user: " + err);
        }
        else {
            res.format({
                html: function () {
                    res.redirect("/");
                }
            });
        }
    })
}

function sendErrorResponse(err, req, res) {
    res.status(500);
    res.send("Failed to switch user " + err);
}

function sendNotFoundResponse(req, res) {
    res.status(404);
    res.send("Could not find user");
}
```

Now depending on what version of Mongoose JS you are using, a limited version of Promises may be [available already](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html). Your code could be cleaned up even further like so.

```
router.route('/switchuser')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        mongoose.model('Users').findById(req.body.idOrName)
            .then(function (user) {
                // If the user was found, return it down the chain
                if (user) {
                    return user;
                }

                // If the user was not found, return the promise for the next query
                return mongoose.model('Users').findOne({ username: req.body.idOrName });
            })
            .then(function(user) {
                if (!user) {
                    sendNotFoundResponse(req, res);
                    return;
                }

                loginAs(user, req, res);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                sendErrorResponse(err, req, res);
            });
    });
});

function loginAs(user, req, res) {
    req.login(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404);
            res.send("There was a problem switching the user: " + err);
        }
        else {
            res.format({
                html: function () {
                    res.redirect("/");
                }
            });
        }
    })
}

function sendErrorResponse(err, req, res) {
    res.status(500);
    res.send("Failed to switch user " + err);
}

function sendNotFoundResponse(req, res) {
    res.status(404);
    res.send("Could not find user");
}
```

You'll notice with promises you can lump all the errors together at the bottom in a single `catch`. Cleaner result with less duplicate code and methods calls. You may need to perform an `exec` to get access to the `catch` method. Just read the Mongoose docs and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It worked fine, but I had to remove first if clause 'if (err)', otherwise it wasn't working.